# Change email of a user with Firebase simple login

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin, firebase-authentication

If I have a user that logged in with email/password is there any way to change that user’s email address on the backend?

I see I can have the user change it themselves with oldEmail, newEmail, password:

```
ref.changeEmail({
  oldEmail : "bobtony@firebase.com",
  newEmail : "bobtony@google.com",
  password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("Email changed successfully");
} else {
    console.log("Error changing email:", error);
}
```

But is there any way for me to change it for them without the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Firebase support: There is no way to change the user's email address without the password.